# await message.channel.send(response.text) NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord, discord.py

I have tried to run this code, and the discord bot does turn on, but when I try and type '$joke' in discord it returns this error:    `await message.channel.send(response.text) NameError: name 'response' is not defined` I'm quite new to this so i'm not really sure what exactly the problem here is. here is my code:

```
import os
import requests
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


client = discord.Client()

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(quote)


def get_meme():
    url = "https://ronreiter-meme-generator.p.rapidapi.com/meme"
    querystring = {"top":"haha MEME","bottom":"from Photon#2400","meme":"Condescending-Wonka","font_size":"50","font":"Impact"}
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "ronreiter-meme-generator.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "443da94d87mshc53009d5fb1dca7p189387jsn7ca32834f0b6"
        }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    return(response)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

    if message.content.startswith('$quote'):
        quote=get_quote()
        await message.channel.send(quote)
        
    if message.content.startswith('$whoami'):
        await message.channel.send('You are {}'.format(message.author.name))
        
    if message.content.startswith("$joke"):
        await message.channel.send(response.text)
        
        
        
client.run(os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN'))
```

Comment: where did you define `response` within `on_message`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I just realised I didn't, it's because i hadn't called get_meme() so there was no `response` for it to send

Answer (score 0):

try install Django rest framework -drf

`from rest_framework.response import Response`